# java.io.FileNotFoundException when playing ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I want to play Ringtone for Incoming Call. I do like below for that,

```
Uri defaultRingToneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            if(currentRingtonePlayer != null ){
                stopRingTonePlayer();
            }
            currentRingtonePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            currentRingtonePlayer.setDataSource(this, defaultRingToneUri);
            currentRingtonePlayer.setLooping(true);
            currentRingtonePlayer.prepare();
            currentRingtonePlayer.start();
```

Using this code ringtone is played. But I am getting below exception,

```
2021-03-16 11:59:05.415 12096-12096/ W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://0@settings/system/ringtone_cache
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:149)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1700)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1516)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1433)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1157)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1106)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1022)
        at com.CallActivity.playRingTone(CallActivity.java:620)
        at com.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:348)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

In my case ringtone is played. Eventhough I am getting this exception. Anybody have any idea why this happens? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whats the file type of ringtone? Did try to change to another type of media to see if  problem still?

Comment: @Anna No I doesn't know the filetype. I am using RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE  which is used for phone ring

Answer (score 0):

How about use getActualDefaultRingtoneUri

```
Uri defaultRingToneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(mContext, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

Comment: This resolved the error for me. Only change I made is replacing mContext with getApplicationContext()